# I'm unable to install MongoDB in my Ubuntu system and I face this error while installing

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, installation

Unpacking mongodb-org (4.2.6) ...

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_4.2.6_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_4.2.6_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-tools_4.2.6_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Can you include more information? Maybe a more detailed error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest you to stop everything running on your server. Such as Nginx or Apache or node.js process...

Try to upgrade your Ubuntu instance. And try these commands.

```sh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y mongodb
sudo systemctl enable mongodb
sudo systemctl enable mongodb.service
sudo systemctl start mongodb
```